# LUA 5.4 - How to convert 64-bit numbers to hex

Tags: lua, hex, 64-bit, biginteger

I wanted to convert numbers greater than 64 bits, including up to 256 bits number from decimal to hex in lua.

Example:

```
num = 9223372036854775807
num = string.format("%x", num)
num = tostring(num)
print(num) -- output is 7fffffffffffffff
```

but if I already add a single number, it returns an error in the example below:

```
num = 9223372036854775808
num = string.format("%x", num)
num = tostring(num)
print(num) -- error lua54 - bad argument #2 to 'format' (number has no integer representation)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to convert numbers greater than 64 bits, including up to 256 bits number from decimal to hex in lua.

Well that's not possible without involving a big integer library such as [this one](https://github.com/JorjBauer/lua-bigint). Lua 5.4 has two number types: 64-bit signed integers and 64-bit floats, which are both to limited to store arbitrary 256-bit integers.

The first num in your example, `9223372036854775807`, is just the upper limit of int64 bounds (`-2^63` to `2^63-1`, both inclusive). Adding `1` to this forces Lua to cast it into a float64, which can represent numbers way larger than that at the cost of precision. You're then left with an imprecise float which has no "integer representation" as Lua tells you.

You *could* trivially reimplement `%x` yourself, but that wouldn't help you extend the precision/size of floats & ints. You need to find another number representation and find or write a bigint library to go with it. Options are:

- String representation: Represent numbers as hex- or bytestrings (base 256).
- Table representation: Represent numbers as lists of numbers (base 2^x where x is < 64)